# How can I mutate the state of a C# Quartz JobDataMap in a Job?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm using C# [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) as part of a command line application. A job `SomeDataReadoutJob` (which shall not be executed concurrently `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]`) is used to read data out from somewhere. I want to preserve the state of a variable (here: `someDouble`, `[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]`) in the `JobDataMap` across several executions of the job. To get the value of `someDouble` I use `double someDouble = dataMap.GetDouble("someDouble");`. I know how to set the value during initialization.

```cs
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SomeDataReadoutJob>()
        .WithIdentity("someDataReadoutJob", "groupDataReadout")
        .UsingJobData("someDouble", 0.0)
        .Build();
```

The job is then scheduled every second (`.WithIntervalInSeconds(1)`) and running forever (`.RepeatForever()`).

```
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("dataReadoutTrigger", "groupDataReadout")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
            .RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

But I could not find any info in the docs about how to set a value inside a job. On GitHub I've found Quartz jobs which [seemed to store state leading to  `dataMap["someDouble"] = someDouble;`](https://github.com/huayumeng/intime.apis/blob/575f812da80d30032e0b7d1140bb64c1d44ae7a0/com.intime.jobscheduler/Job/Push2awsIncreJob.cs#L15-L22). But the state is updated only once: `0.0`, `0.1`, `0.1`, `0.1`, ...

```cs
        [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
        [PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
        public class SomeDataReadoutJob : IJob
        {
            public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
                    double someDouble = dataMap.GetDouble("someDouble");
                    // State should be preserved across job executions and the print statement print accordingly (0.0, 0.1, ...).
                    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{someDouble}");
                    // Mutate the state of someDouble.
                    someDouble =+ 0.1;
                    // How can I write the mutated state back into the dataMap?
                    // I've tried
                    // dataMap.Put("someDouble", someDouble);
                    // as well as
                    // dataMap["someDouble"] = someDouble;
                    // but the state was updated only once: 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ...
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new JobExecutionException();
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I set values in `JobDataMap` to preserve it across job execcutions?

Comment: Is your job being kept alive, i.e. are there triggers referencing it? `dataMap.Put` put should store the data and if the job is going to fire again it should be persisted.

Comment: I don't know yet. How can I check that?